# Microsoft GraphAPI working in one project, but not another

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a console app using the Graph API to process pdfs sent to an email address. I am trying to set up my api to serve the pdfs, which is in another project. I have my authentication and client creation for graph in a dll, so that is all done the same, and uses the same Azure AD application info. In the console app, everything works great, but in the API it is not working.Do I have to provision the API as a separate app in Azure? That's all I can think of. Te code is literally the same right now, and not working. No errors or anything, just hangs forever trying to get anything from Office 365.

Thanks.
The below is the working code:

```
try
            {
                client = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Acquiring a token failed with the following 
    error: {0}", ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    //You should implement retry and back-off logic per the 
    guidance given here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168916.aspx
                    //InnerException Message will contain the HTTP error status 
    codes mentioned in the link above
                    Console.WriteLine("Error detail: {0}", 
    ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                String email = "mail@example.com";
                Console.WriteLine("\nRetreiving email from: " + email);
                var folders = client.Users[email].MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

This is the code that fails:

```
try
        {
            client = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Acquiring a token failed with the following error: {0}", ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                //You should implement retry and back-off logic per the guidance given here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn168916.aspx
                //InnerException Message will contain the HTTP error status codes mentioned in the link above
                Console.WriteLine("Error detail: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ReadKey();
            return null;
        }
        Attachment attachment = null;
        try
        {
            String email = "email@example.com";

            var folders = client.Users[email].MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Its tough to get into your problem without having look into your code.

Comment: I added the code, but it's basically identical.

Comment: @Paul does your API call console? Can you show the AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp code? You might be losing context during async calls.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla I will take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Is the API using the same ClientID and ClientSecret? What's the exception message thats showing up? Can you share it?

Comment: @rasharasha There is no exception, the call just never returns. Same ClientId and Secret.

Comment: Can you use something like Fiddler to see if the network request is made? and inspect the body to see what is being sent out?